# How to create a failover window service?

Tags: c#, windows-services, high-availability

i have an requirements where i need to have two instances of the custom window service code running at the same time but only one should be doing the work until the other one fails or die.

i'm trying to come up with the clean and simple design to do this.

one way:

1. create a temp table
2. and have this two service talk to each other via the table
3. and if the running one goes down, using probably last modified date
   time on the table
4. then the other one will start

but this is very manual. i'm using c# 4.0.

are there better ways to achieve this?

i saw there's something like [EventWaitHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.eventwaithandle%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) but not sure if it would be simple to use it.

thanks
~m

Comment: WaitHandle only works when your service is still alive, otherwise the handle wouldn't be triggered. Rethink... How to detect that the service is down?

Comment: mm i was hoping that it could automatically trigger the reset event on shutdown or on exception? so it doesnt? and does it work across diff machines within the same network?

Comment: Won't what ever killed the first service kill the second service?

Comment: IMO; High Availability is not simple. That's your answer.

Comment: If your service receives a request for shutdown you can respond to it by notifying [something]. But what happens when the machine on which the service runs dies? [disaster case but still...]

Comment: Won't your Windows service auto-restart if it terminates abnormally?

Comment: How about checking for Process ID or another service that automatically starts the service if required

Comment: yup but the idea here is simply it fail maybe due to hardware failure, so since both service are in two separate server, we would have a spare.

Comment: What about using a named pipe, sockets, WCF or similar to have both services talking to each other and a non-response triggers your code to check if other service is alive or not.

Answer (score 0):

1. Implement a kind of lock/mutex using a common database (as you mentioned)
2. If the instances on the different servers know of each other (config?), they can chat with each other and decide who's boss.
3. If the instances do not know of each other try using an UDP broadcast to announce themselves to each other and then decide who's boss.

If you are able to do #1 and do it generic exposing it through a web service that solution would be reusable for other applications as well. I use such a solution myself.

Answer (score -1):

Consider exposing a ping api endpoint (simple Rest API ping method) on both services so that each can monitor the other service state.

Comment: then it's not useful for my purpose here... :(

Comment: I did not know your services were on different machine. Have you considered exposing an interface (simple wcf ping method)  on both services so that each can monitor the other service state?